# WordPress Popular Posts Table Size Is Getting Big

Tags: plugins

I uninstalled [WordPress Popular Posts](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/) plugin because it is getting slow lately. By digging to my database, I found that the table wp_popularpostsdatacache which is part of WordPress Popular Posts plugin is getting big. Currently it has 3,501,405 rows with 160.7 MiB used space.

I am thinking that this record was not cleaned because I am using nginx instead of apache. This happens to me on my Drupal site also. But I cannot confirm this. So, do you think this is because of nginx? If not, why it is getting bigger and bigger? It seems that the record there is not deleted.

I am using "Last 24 hours" option in Time Range option of this plugin. So I think a record of yesterday will be deleted automatically. But this is not the case.

Any idea about this?

Comment: Please link to that plugin.

Comment: Please: Additional info always as [edit] to the question.

Comment: Sorry for that. I already edited my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really an issue with the plugin; I'd ask the plugin author for support.

If you are no longer using the plugin, use adminer or phpmyadmin to drop the `wp_popularpostsdatacache` table from the database.